# python 2.7 / pyqt5 and pyinstaller : sip module error

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, pyqt5, pyinstaller, python-sip

after trying pyqt5 with python3.+ i had some problems with the code than i used python2.7 + pyqt5(for python2.7) and everything worked fine from pycharm and when i run the script from cmd.
now the problem with pyinstaller
pyqt4 / python 2.7 : pyinstaller compile the script and worked fine
pyqt5 / python 2.7 : pyinstaller compile the script but don't work and i capture an error that no module named sip.
the last version of sip 4.19 available only for python3.
if add : import sip to the code i see another error message :
application faild to start because it could not find or load th Qt platform plugin "windows"
all these versions the same problem :
python 2.7.1 / python 2.7.9 / anaconda(python2.7) / winpython(python2.7)
the code :

```
import sys
import sip
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello")
button.setFixedSize(100, 50)
button.show()
app.exec_()
```